# What to write to activate an action under didSelectRowAt if the cell is in Section: 5 Row: 0

Tags: uitableview

I know "if indexPath.section == x or if indexPath.row == x { " to activate the button in particular row.

If my cell is at section 5 row 0, what is the proper way to write to activate the action in that cell?

Edit (more info more code)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    let name = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = name
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(name)   Section:\(indexPath.section) Row:\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

    return cell
}
```

cause I used disclosureIndicator I could see section # & row # of all my TableCells.

My section 5 has only one row which is "Sign Out" so I had:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.section == 5 {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: .destructive, handler: { (_) in
            do {
               //... ...//
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

However, my other sections have multiple rows. Thus, what should I write if I want to perform an action in Section 4 Row 2?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please see the Edit

Comment: I got it. It is:  if indexPath.section == 4 && indexPath.row == 2 {
            
        }